# Using iFrame's OnSubmit function for a Parent Window's Button's OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, submit

Basically, I want to use this HTML Form (Which loads in an iframe on a parent page) to submit using a parent page's button that when clicked will submit using the iFrame's built-in OnSubmit function. The problem here is that I could just use the javascript code with document.getElementById('Cable_Extraction_Worksheet').contentWindow.uploaddata(); which would fire off the required function in the JS, but I need to use the form's onsubmit and action attributes because the form needs to redirect correctly and send session variables, only on submit, to be loaded on the NEXT form that is being called via the form's action. HELP? Any better way to do this since I am stuck using iFrames? Tried using php include, but the HTML and CSS is terribly misconstrued in the parent window.

Code is simplified for sample purposes.

IFRAME HTML

```
<form name="prepform" method="post" onsubmit="uploaddata();" action="http://gp21.idmyasset.com/mobile/prep_b/index.php">
HTML CODE HERE
</form>
```

PARENT HTML

```
<div data-role="content">
            <iframe src="prep_new/index.html"
            frameborder="" name="prep_new" id="prep_new" class="contentiframe"></iframe>
</div>
<li>
            <a onclick="document.getElementById('prep_new').contentWindow.document.forms['prepform'].submit();" data-transition="flip" data-theme="" data-icon="check">
                  Continue
            </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found another way to implement this...

Comment: Can you share the way you fixed it? @jflay